# Jenkins Pipeline ansible plugin: Ansible-playbook fails

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an Ansible playbook I am trying to run from a Jenkins pipeline. I have Ansible running from source and I am calling it with the Ansible plugin. Here's the bit from my pipeline script:

```
withEnv(["PYTHONPATH=/home/ec2-user/ansible/lib"]) {
                ansiblePlaybook([
                    colorized: true,
                    credentialsId: 'my-creds',
                    installation: 'ansible-2-2-0',
                    inventory: 'staging',
                    playbook: 'deploy.yml',
                    extras: "--extra-vars 'app_build_id=${git_commit}'"
                ])

            }
```

I have verified that the path to the Ansible executable is correct, and so is $PYTHONPATH. But here's what it does when I run the pipeline:

```
[Pipeline] ansiblePlaybook
[planet-healthcare-pipeline] $ /home/ec2-user/ansible/bin/ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i staging -f 5 --private-key /home/ec2-user/jenkins/workspace/REDACTED.key -u ec2-user --extra-vars app_build_id=24a6431
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/ansible/bin/ansible-playbook", line 43, in <module>
    import ansible.constants as C
ImportError: No module named ansible.constants
FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:227)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:226)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] mail
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Ansible playbook execution failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Why can't Ansible load its own constants?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it as user jenkins

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Comment: How? What you mean by run it as a user Jenkins. A screen shot will help.